# I want to send the latest record in a table in Access through Outlook

Tags: ms-access-2010

I want to send the latest record in a table in Access as email through Outlook. I need the email to look like the image in the below.

<https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmrhK.jpg>

This may be simple for experienced Ms Access users but I haven't tried using this feature before. You're help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have VBA code in MS-Access now that sends the email without your data? Do you have a form that opens to the record(s) selected? Where are you now in your attempts?

Comment: I got it resolved somehow. Thanks!